# react native netinfo returns true when there is no data connection

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reachability, react-native-community-netinfo

I have an issue with the `react-native-community/netinfo` package

My `react-native-community/netinfo` version is 9.5.0, and my `react native` version is 0.70.7.

The react version is 18.1.0

I use `isInternetReachable` to detect internet reachability and the problem is when I connect with Wi-Fi, but with no data connection the `isInternetReachable` still returns `true`. How can I fix it?

I tried every listeners and every possible way that i found in the documentation, but I'm not getting a result.

Can someone help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: Add some code . what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

NetInfo streams the updates from the native side directly w/o any computation. This sometimes brings undesired behavior.

https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo?tab=readme-ov-file#addeventlistener

> Subscribe to connection information. The callback is called with a
> parameter of type NetInfoState whenever the connection state changes.
> Your listener will be called with the latest information soon after
> you subscribe and then with any subsequent changes afterwards. You
> should not assume that the listener is called in the same way across
> devices or platforms.

##### Solution

Netinfo can ping you up to 5+ times whenever the network state is changed, what works for me is to debounce the event listener response for a second, this way it is working as expected. Also, the library doesn't work with iOS Simulator well, you need to test it on a real device.

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash'
const DEBOUNCE_DURATION = 1000
...
React.useEffect(() => {
    const debouncedListener = debounce((response) => {
        console.log('netInfo response': response)
    }, DEBOUNCE_DURATION)
    const unsubscribe = netInfo.addEventListener((response) => {
        debouncedListener(response)
    })

    return () => {
        // cancel the debounced function when unsubscribing
        debouncedListener.cancel()
        // unsubscribe
        unsubscribe()
    }
}, [])
```

##### If you want to solve the issue when the network connection is coming from a hotspot.

You need to use not only `isConnected` flat but also `isInternetReachable`. If that is not working for you, you can apply a logic where every time netInfo returns isConnected && isInternetReachable true, you can integrate https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ping and do a double-check, after your event listener emits

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash'
const DEBOUNCE_DURATION = 1000
...
React.useEffect(() => {
    const debouncedListener = debounce((response) => {
        console.log('netInfo response': response)
        // assuming that isConnected && isInternetReachable are both true.
        try {
            const ms = await Ping.start('114.114.114.114',{ 
            timeout: 1000 });
            // YOU HAVE INTERNET CONNECTION
        } catch (error) {
            // YOU ARE OFFLINE
        }
    }, DEBOUNCE_DURATION)
    const unsubscribe = netInfo.addEventListener((response) => {
        debouncedListener(response)
    })

    return () => {
        // cancel the debounced function when unsubscribing
        debouncedListener.cancel()
        // unsubscribe
        unsubscribe()
    }
}, [])
```

Comment: it gives same result </3

Comment: Are you testing it on the simulator? What is your environment?

Comment: no I tried it on my phone and a pose device

Comment: let me explain clearly I connected my device to another device's hotspot and the device I connected to has no access to the internet however Netinfo.isInternetReachable returns true.

Comment: Ohh, yes there was such use-case. I remember arguing with the QA team about this. Alright. let me know my answer.

Comment: do you have any Solution's 

Comment: do you have any solution's for this?

Comment: that was nice one tnx for help I will try it and tell you the result